# How can I explicitly express the Ising Hamiltonian in matrix form?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, computational-physics, ising-model, spin-chains

I am reading [this](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783030014087) book about numerical methods in physics. It has the following question:

> Consider the Ising Hamiltonian defined as following $$H=-\sum_ {i=1}^{N-1} 
> \sigma_i^x \sigma_ {i+1} ^x + h \sum_ {i=1} ^N \sigma_i^z$$
>
> Write a program that computes the $2^N \times 2^N$ matrix for
>   different $N$

From quantum mechanics, I know that any operator can be expressed in matrix form as follows
$$H_{rs}\dot{=}\langle r |H|s\rangle$$
where $|i\rangle$ are any basis.

My question is what basis can I take for this Hamiltonian? Is there any other way to write this Hamiltonian in matrix form?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87671/discussion-on-question-by-luqman-saleem-how-can-i-explicitly-express-the-ising-h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness I'll summarize the answer here. After a fun conversation in the comments, we saw that it will be more illuminating to write

$$H=-\sum_ {i=1}^{N-1} 
\sigma_i^x \sigma_ {i+1} ^x + h \sum_ {i=1} ^N \sigma_i^z $$

as

$$ H=-\sum_ {i=1}^{N-1} 
\sigma_i^x  \sigma_ {i+1} ^x + h\left( \sum_ {i=1} ^{N-1} 1_1 \otimes \cdots 1_{i-1} \otimes \sigma_i^z \otimes 1_{i+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes 1_{N-1} \right)
+ h ( 1_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1_{N-1} \otimes \sigma^z_N) $$

where it is understood that (to prevent clutter)

$$ \sigma_i^x  \sigma_{i+1}^x = 1_1 \otimes \cdots\otimes 1_{i-1} \otimes \sigma^x_i \otimes \sigma^x_{i+1} \otimes 1_{i+2} \otimes \cdots \otimes 1_{N} $$

and the subscripts are there to denote nothing more than the position of insertion (i.e. they are all $2\times 2$ identity)

We then create a matrix from the direct product of matrices $A,B$ where $[A] = m \times n$  and $[B] = p \times q$ matrices

$$ \mathbf {A} \otimes \mathbf {B} ={\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\mathbf {B} &\cdots &a_{1n}\mathbf {B} \\\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\a_{m1}\mathbf {B} &\cdots &a_{mn}\mathbf {B} \end{bmatrix}}. $$

We apply this to the $i^{th}$ term and then loop over all $i$ to achieve the desired matrix.

Comment: Your tensor product notation doesn't make sense: $\sigma_N^z$ is $\sigma^z$ acting on site $N$. You can't tensor this with $I_N$, which is $I$ acting on site $N$.  You want to rather tensor it with $I$ on all other sites -- that's the *definition* of $\sigma_N^z$.

Comment: You're right. Thank you. I've made an edit but the notation is a bit sloppy still.

Comment: Much better, but for consistency you should also add the identities in the first term!

Comment: Will do, gonna do that now

Comment: For completeness -- if you don't put the $I$'s in the formula: (i) The last should be $I_N$, not $I_{N-1}$.  (ii) In that case, the product in the main formula should be a *normal* product.

Comment: Agh you're right.. counting is hard.. I believe I addressed the concern. What do you mean by normal product?

Comment: Well, just the product of the operators/matrices: $\sigma^x_{i}\sigma^x_{i+1}$.  After all, both $\sigma^x_{i}$ and $\sigma_x^{i+1}$ *are* operators defined on the full $2^N$-dimensional space -- you don't want to take their tensor product.

Comment: I see. Yes, that would screw up things dimensionally. Thanks a lot for clearing everything up.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Quick hint :}$

Interpret spin operators (for chain of length-N) this way (spin operators act on [tensor product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)) :
$$\sigma_{i}^{\alpha} \rightarrow\underset{N_{}^{\text{th}}\text{order direct/kronecker product of identity and pauli matrices}}{\mathbb{I}_{}^{}\otimes\cdots\otimes\underset{i_{}^{\text{th}} \text{position}}{\sigma_{}^{\alpha}}\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathbb{I}_{}^{}}$$
which makes (for $i < j$):

$$\sigma_{i}^{\alpha}\sigma_{j}^{\beta} \stackrel{i < j}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{I}_{}^{}\otimes\cdots\otimes\underset{i_{}^{\text{th}} \text{position}}{\sigma_{}^{\alpha}}\otimes\cdots\otimes\underset{j_{}^{\text{th}} \text{position}}{\sigma_{}^{\beta}}\otimes \cdots\otimes\mathbb{I}_{}^{}$$
with standard definition of [direct/Kronecker product of matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

Note also that Kronecker product is associative.

$\mathbb{I}$ is $2 \times 2$ identity matrix and $\sigma_{}^{}$'s are standard [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).