# Potts model Hamiltonian

Tags: hamiltonian, ising-model

I wonder about the Hmiltonian form fo the Potts model and would like to know about its matrix form using the generalized Pauli matrix.

I believe it might be possible in a smiliar way applied to the Ising model, as you can see in the website below:

[How can I explicitly express the Ising Hamiltonian in matrix form?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451075/how-can-i-explicitly-express-the-ising-hamiltonian-in-matrix-form)

I'm not sure if it's just changing the Pauli matrix into generalized form from the Ising model.

Comment: It's hard to follow your question. Please edit the question to make it understandable